# PHP: sort array by half-hour intervals

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a very specific problem here.  I have a multi-dimensional array that I want to sort first by half-hour time intervals, second by dates.  The function [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) will not meet my requirements.

Example: I want:

```
array(array("time"=>"12:15",
            "date"=>"2009-03-24"),
      array("time"=>"12:10",
            "date"=>"2009-03-23"),
      array("time"=>"12:00",
            "date"=>"2009-03-24"),
      array("time"=>"11:30",
            "date"=>"2009-03-24"));
```

To end up as:

```
array(array("time"=>"11:30",
            "date"=>"2009-03-24"),
      array("time"=>"12:10",
            "date"=>"2009-03-23"),
      array("time"=>"12:00",
            "date"=>"2009-03-24"),
      array("time"=>"12:15",
            "date"=>"2009-03-24"));
```

I've tried to accomplish this with [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) in combination with my own sorting callback function.  This is the code I am currently using:

```
uksort($myArray, "sortThirties");

function sortThirties($a, $b)
{
    //Get the two times as timestamps relative to today
    $one = strtotime($a['time']);
    $two = strtotime($b['time']);

    //Round them down to the nearest half-hour time
    $one = $one - ($one % 1800);
    $two = $two - ($two % 1800);

    //Return the difference if times are unequal
    //If times are equal, return the difference between dates.
    return ($one == $two ? strcmp($a['date'],$b['date']) : $one - $two);
}
```

Immediately after running this function, I print out the array with print_r(), and the order of the data appears to be random.  What am I missing?

**EDIT**:
It turns out, the order **is** *completely* random.  I added this line to the sortThirties function:

```
echo "<BR>",$a['time']," ",$b['time'];
```

and all I got was 50 pages of `<BR>`'s.

I know the array is correctly structured because this code executed on the very same array gives me the unsorted data:

```
foreach($myArray AS $a)
{
    echo "<BR>",$a['date']," ",$a['time'];
}
```

The only thing I can think of is there must be a problem with uksort.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **uksort** function sorts the array by keys while **usort** sorts the array by value and your array to be sorted is acctualy:

```
$to_sort = array( 
                  0 => array("time"=>"12:15", "date"=>"2009-03-24"),
                  1 => array("time"=>"12:10", "date"=>"2009-03-23"),
                  2 => array("time"=>"12:00", "date"=>"2009-03-24"),
                  3 => array("time"=>"11:30", "date"=>"2009-03-24")
                );
```

Do you see the difference? :)

Comment: Yeesh...  Did I really just ask everyone on the Internet why I'm an idiot?  Thanks for being kind.  I don't know why I couldn't figure that out yesterday.  For some reason, I saw the example on the php docs and saw the keys ("the earth", "an apple", etc.) as values.

Comment: Don't worry, sometimes it happens to miss something like that and that's when sites like this one come in handy. I'm glad that I could help :).

Answer (score 2):

Very odd.  I just tried your code on an array similar to the one you provided, and it worked great.  Possibilities:

- extra whitespace on any of the array times/dates?
- PHP version differences?  I noticed that the return value of strtotime() was changed in PHP version 5.1.0

Comment: Some versions of PHP require the date to be passed with the time in strtotime.  This could be his problem.

Comment: I have tested this on the same system the sorting code is running on.  strtotime("15:30") returns a unix timestamp for today's date at 3:30pm.